# Jquery & css does not work on server when using Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute method in Global.asax file in MVC

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, localization, global-asax

I have developed one MVC4 aplication & in that i have made Validation message Localize. So i have used ' Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute() ' this method in my application Global.asax file. It work on Localhost , but when i publish the application then css & jquery does not work on iis server. If i does not use this ' Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute() ' method then work well on iis server also. Whenever i am going to use this method in my Global.asax file, then it work on localhost, but does not work well on iis server i.e. css & jquery does not work on server. So can i have to make some configuration in web.config or any where else ?

So what is the problem? Can anyone Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be chance of null reference error in your code.
Whatever you have used in this method please check for this possible problem.

It does not require any thing to be configured in web.config.